# Newly created claim in WSO2 IS not visible for SP

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I've tried with both WSO2 IS versions 5.4.0 and 5.5.0 to create a custom claim into both Local claim dialect and OIDC claim dialect. Both are created successfully and are listed in the claim lists.

But when I try to add that claim to an SP's Claim Configuration, the claim is not visible in the Local Claim drop-down menu.

I noticed that for the new claim, there's no entry added to the UM_CLAIM table. If I add it manually, then the claim appears for selection for the SP.

Am I creating the claims somehow wrong, or is there something in the SP's configuration preventing the claim from being selectable?

Comment: I tried this scenario in the latest build and it worked fine. Have you tried this in a migrated setup or a fresh pack? Claim mappings are no longer added to the UM_CLAIM table. Can you check whether the initializeNewClaimManager property is set to true in the user-mgt.xml file

Comment: Thanks for the comment and advise. I forgot to mention that it's a migration. I'll have to check if the DB migration actually went through successfully or not.

Comment: Can you check if the initializeNewClaimManager property is set to true in the user-mgt.xml file

Comment: Apparently the "user-mgt.xml" file was a mix-up between 5.2.0 and 5.4.0 (this was our own error). Fixing that fixed also claim creation. Thank you!